# What should I do with old (project) websites / historic content?

Tags: content, static-content

I have a few old websites with some nice content, artist projects. Not relevant for business but quite interesting in a historical way.

My feeling says it would be not enought to keep the page alive, because it  would be just another oldfashioned site. Maybe it would be a good idea to frame it by some infos.

The companies which initially run the websites doesn't exists anymore. So it also would be a legal problem, the imprint and legal notices aren't up to date. (I do have the right to publish the initial material).

Do you have any experience with that kind of content?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem. I want to build a portfolio of my recent work but also show off my old work (similarly, most of the companies don't exist anymore).

My approach is to record a .gif of me navigating and showing off the website using a tool like ScreenToGif. Then I put that .gif on my website.

If you want your websites to actually be on the Internet and let users browse them; put them under "archives" folder on your server, something like:

example.com/archives/my-old-site1

example.com/archives/my-old-site1